help me to transfer my ETH from my scroll safe wallet
after I entered this command
send_ether 0x1E2025dB1A3a4400b6b0adB8dE12B7E0CFb7D47c 100000000000000000 8
showing this error
error: unrecognized arguments: 8
why please help

To add a nonce to the command you need to specify --safe-nonce before your argument (before 8 in your case).
Hope it helps! Best, Louis
